# How to Perform Insert Operation with DbLink in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I am tying to perform insert with dblink in postgres but it is throwing error
column "Test" does not exist

```
Select * 
from dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=Test dbname=wb',
            'Insert Into tblProducts(AccountNumber,AccountProductNumber,supplierproductnumber)
             Values( 2012, 2022,'Test') Returning ProductNumber'
     ) AS tblProducts(ProductNumber integer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes within the payload, using an additional quote '' (two single quotes):

```
Select * 
from dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=Test dbname=wb',
            'Insert Into tblProducts(AccountNumber,AccountProductNumber,supplierproductnumber)
             Values( 2012, 2022,''Test'') Returning ProductNumber'
     ) AS tblProducts(ProductNumber integer);
```